# Android wear: Weather API

Tags: android, api, wear-os, weather-api

I am currently developing my second watch face for android wear and i wanted to incorporate the weather on the screen either in text or a little icon. Whats the best way to do this?

Can you call anything in the android system or will it have to be an API, any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.forecast.io/ You can register here, you will get the data in JSON format.

You can set both text and icon.

You need to use HTTP get request using Volley library or any, then after recieving the response from the server in String format, you need to parse the JSON and store it in Java objects, and set the text views according to the values stored in objects.

You can check this project [Weather App](https://github.com/kenwalger/Stormy)

Comment: I'm not sure what i do with it from there?

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate this :)